# XML Elements to Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to show all the info I need from an XML to a datagridview1. The XML has a `<Product>` tag that contains it's own attributes and several Elements with it's own Attributes.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Import>
    <Products>
        <Product Id="1" Name="prodcut1">
            <Prices price=10,10/>
            <Barcodes barcode="123123123123"/>
        </Product>

        <Product Id="2" Name="Product2">
            <Prices price=9,9/>
            <Barcodes Barcode="123123123123"/>
        </Product>


    </Products>

</Import>
```

Since a datagridview as far as I know, cant show more than one table (ie. `dataGrid1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1];`), I was trying with Linq and anonymous types to select whatever I want and show it in one line per `<Product>` tag. 
On the datagrid it should look like something like this:

```
id | Name         | Barcode | Price
1   product1        123...      10,10
2   product2        123....     9,9
```

So far I wrote this to show `<Product>` and its attributes, 'id' and 'name':

```
XElement ProdXML = XElement.Load(@"C:\Export\ppp.xml");
var query = from st in ProdXML.Descendants("Product")
            select new
            {
                Id = st.Attribute("Id").Value,
                name = st.Attribute("Name").Value,

             };
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Is there any way to retrieve `Prices => Price` and `Barcodes => barcode` inside the `Select`?

Comment: Well yes, use `st.Element("Prices")` to get the `Prices` element etc. Note that your XML is currently invalid, and I'd really *hope* that it would use `.` as the decimal separator rather than `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you only need to access the element:

```
XElement ProdXML = XElement.Load(@"C:\Export\ppp.xml");
            var query = from st in ProdXML.Descendants("Product")

select new
{
    Id = st.Attribute("Id").Value,
    name = st.Attribute("Name").Value,
    price = st.Element("Prices").Attribute("Price").Value,
    barcode = st.Element("Barcodes").Attribute("Barcode").Value
};
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with xml deserializer, it will be easier to use. You can then convert into list objects and play with it.

something like:

```
string xml = "";//Get xml here            
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Import));
var import = (Import)serializer.Deserialize(xml);
```

Use `System.Xml.Serialization` Namespace

The classes that you can use can be like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Prices")]
public class Prices
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Barcodes")]
public class Barcodes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "barcode")]
    public List<string> Barcode { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Prices")]
    public Prices Prices { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Barcodes")]
    public Barcodes Barcodes { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Products")]
public class Products
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product")]
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Import")]
public class Import
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Products")]
    public Products Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to play with them, For now I just need to show the values, so Sebastian solution works fine so far. Thanks a lot tho.